# Остановить отправку формы через submit если ajax запрос вернул null

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $( "#reqform" ).submit(function( event, data ) {
          $.ajax({
            url: "scripts/checksubmit.php",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {street : $('#adres').val(),
                   house : $('#house').val()
                  },
            success: function(data) {
                  if (data == null) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    alert('Не равно');
                    } else {
                    alert('Равно');
                        }
                    }
            })
        });
```

Собственно alert-ы работают исправно, не выполняется лишь та часть где event.oreventDefault(); Форма всё равно отправляется не смотря на то, что ajax вернул null хотя Alert говорит что пришёл null. Что может быть не так ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К моменту вызова асинхронного `ajax.success`, обработчик `$("#reqform").submit` давно отработал.  `event.preventDefault();` надо вызывать внутри `$("#reqform").submit`, нe в `ajax.success`. В случае благоприятного результата `ajax` запроса, вызывайте `$( "#reqform" )[0].submit();`, где `.submit()` - это native метод, чтобы избежать повторного вызова  `$("#reqform").submit`.

```
$("#reqform").sbmit(function( event, data ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "scripts/checksubmit.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {street : $('#adres').val(),
               house : $('#house').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == null) {
                alert('Не равно');
            } else {
                alert('Равно');
                $( "#reqform" )[0].submit();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Немного затупил, сейчас проверю

Comment: Вы совершенно правы, надо было разобраться с тем как работает preventDefault(); Вопрос надо было ставить иначе - Остановить отправку формы и если ajax вернул !null - отправить форму.